# SDL Web 8.5 - Install legacy API (in-process) files outside the /bin folder of .NET Web application

Tags: web8.5, installation, cis

According to the [documentation to install in-process APIs](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-41262406-9599-4FFE-9563-E9F8CB9FC302#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dapi%2520in%255C-process&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1562663030706&currentQuery=api%2520in%255C-process&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14.xml&docid=GUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false), it is necessary to install both the `lib` folder and the `config` folder and their dlls inside the `\bin` folder of the .NET web application. The problem is that we have several .NET applications and automatic deployment of them, which forces us to centralize these files and dlls in a single external route. Is it possible to install these API files in a unique and different path to the `/bin` folder of the .NET Web application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's possible, I have used in the past,

Alternatively, you can use to setup **TRIDION_HOME** (pointing to the SDL Tridion home directory) is set on this machine, do the following:

1. Create an environment variable **TRIDION_HOME** in your web app server and point to folder eg: D:\Tridion\
2. Copy the **config** and **lib** folders to D:\Tridion\
3. Configuring the JVM for the [legacy API (in-process) Server Role](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-5163B30C-F33E-4648-A887-A50BA86B573D) running in a .NET Web application
4. In your web app ensure to keep the Tridion in-process DLLs based on your setup 64-bit or 32-bit correct assembly, this setup not required to keep lib and config folders under bin folder in your web app.

I did a test on sites 9.0 and it's working so I hope it will work in 8.5 too.

I hope it helps